# How server responds to device for GET request for updating a pass

Tags: ios6, passbook, getresponse

For getting the Latest Version of a Pass, GET request to webServiceURL/version/passes/passTypeIdentifier/serialNumber. What server do to respond to this request ? This is code I use: 
`if (strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) === "GET" && $request[3]==='passes'){
    $passTypeID = $request[4];
    $serial = $request[5];
    $auth_key = str_replace('ApplePass ', '', $headers['Authorization']);
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/PassKit/Reference/PassKit_WebService/WebService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011988).

> - If request is authorized, return HTTP status 200 with a payload of the pass data.
> - If the request is not authorized, return HTTP status 401.
> - Otherwise, return the appropriate standard HTTP status.

The *"payload of the pass data"* means the .pkpass bundle.

Comment: I also saw this already ! but this point, I need to  send . pkpass to device ?

Comment: Yes - if the .pkpass is now different to the .pkpass that is on the device then send the new .pkpass.  Otherwise, just send a `304` "Not Modified" header.

Comment: How can I know .pkpass on device is new or old ?

Comment: So this step, I need to send .pkpass directly or by push notification ?

Comment: before, I use: "<?php   
$pkpass_file = '/path/to/your/.pkpass/file/GenericMemberCard.pkpass';

header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.apple.pkpass");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="pass.pkpass"');
clearstatcache();......." when I click a link to get .pkpass, but now for a pass that is already in user's device. How user can get it automatically ?

Comment: How to set header for'If-Modified-Since' ? I change like this: "str_replace('Last-Modified', $headers['If-Modified-Since']);" ,but not  works! how can I change it ?

Comment: `If-Modified-Since` is a request header sent by the device - you do not send this header in the response.  Instead, you need to set the `Last-Modified` header, then when the device next asks your web service for this file it will send a request with `If-Modified-Since: {value from your Last-Modified header }`

Comment: now I get : Apr  8 15:05:00 CamMobs-iPod4 passd[21] <Warning>: Get serial #s task (for device b6a0503b6e034fc2db8173b4ad752e16, pass type pass.cam-mob.passbookpasstest, last updated 1365406354; with web service url http://192.168.1.202:8888/passesWebserver/) encountered error: Unexpected response code 304

Comment: Because you are responding with `304` to the get serials method.  This method expects a `204` if there are no serials that need updating.

Comment: for getting the latest version of pass, what do I have to put for header: if-modified-since. I have this in this method: if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'])){
     //header('HTTP/1.0 304 Not Modified');
     //exit;
 }

Comment: because there's no $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'], then I get : Apr  8 15:12:24 CamMobs-iPod4 passd[21] <Warning>: Get pass task (pass type pass.cam-mob.passbookpasstest, serial number 0001, if-modified-since (null); with web service url http://192.168.1.202:8888/passesWebserver/) got response with code 304

Comment: but I also get this ; Apr  8 15:12:24 CamMobs-iPod4 passd[21] <Warning>: Get serial numbers task completed with update tag 1365408744, serial numbers (
     0001
 )

Comment: The header you send depends on whether or not you have an updated .pkpass bundle to send - if the bundle has not changed then just send a 304 header and exit, if the bundle has changed DO NOT send a 304, but you will need to send a whole bunch of headers with for the .pkpass file.

Comment: Don't send a 304 header in response to the serials request, you should only send 304 in response to getting the latest version of a pass, and even then you should only send the 304 if the file has not been modified.

Comment: my codes don't work! if (strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) === "GET" && $request[3]==='passes'){
    $passTypeID = $request[4];
    $serial = $request[5];
  $auth_key = str_replace('ApplePass ', '', $headers['Authorization']);
 if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'])){
     //header('HTTP/1.0 304 Not Modified');
     //exit;
 }

 $querySelect = mysql_query("select * from registration");
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($querySelect);
  if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'])){
   if ($passTypeID == $row['passTypeID'] && $serial ==$row['serialNo']){

Comment: $pkpass_file = '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/passesWebserver/DigiClubCardUpdated.pkpass';

   header("Pragma: no-cache");
   header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
   header("Content-type: application/vnd.apple.pkpass; charset=UTF-8");
   header('Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="genericPass.pkpass"');

Comment: clearstatcache();
   $filesize = filesize($pkpass_file);
   if ($filesize)
       header("Content-Length: ". $filesize);
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
   if (filemtime($pkpass_file)) {
       date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
    header('Last-Modified: ' . date("D, d M Y H:i:s", filemtime($pkpass_file)) . ' GMT');
   }
   flush();
   readfile($pkpass_file);
   
   response200();
   }else{
    response401();
   }
  }else{
   response304();
  }
}

Comment: Yes, your code is wrong - your if statement is not triggering so you are sending back an empty response.  Please don't post code in comments.  You have asked this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15873076/how-to-respond-for-getting-pass-task), and there is already an answer showing what the problem is.

Comment: ok ! now my pass is updated, but if-modified-since (null) ! why ?

Comment: what is advantage of if-modified-since ?

Comment: It is used to prevent your server from having to send (and the user's data plan from having to receive) a .pkpass bundle if the .pkpass bundle has not changed since the date provided in the `If-Modified-Since` header.  In simple terms, Passbook is saying to your server please send me this .pkpass file but ONLY if it has not been modified since this date.  It gets this date from the `Last-Modified` header that your server should send whenever it serves a .pkpass bundle.

Comment: this header is not right. can you correct it ? (if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'])){
     //header('HTTP/1.0 304 Not Modified');
     //exit;
 }
)

Comment: Your `header` and `exit` commands are commented out.  Your logs are saying that Passbook is not sending `IF-MODIFIED-SINCE` (I.e. it is null), so this if statement will not trigger because because the superglobal $_SERVER['HTTP-IF-MODIFIED-SINCE'] will also not be set.

Comment: now I can get header of if-modified-since: Apr  8 16:03:19 CamMobs-iPod4 passd[2236] <Warning>: Request contains header field <If-Modified-Since: Mon, 08 Apr 2013 08:51:50 GMT>

Comment: but I get this : Apr  8 16:03:19 CamMobs-iPod4 passd[2236] <Warning>: Web service error for pass.cam-mob.passbookpasstest (http://192.168.1.202:8888/passesWebserver/): Server requested update to serial number '0001', but the pass was unchanged.

Comment: when do I send .pkpass (what condition) ?

Comment: You control your .pkpass.  If you publish a pass on Monday and then you decide to change it on Thursday. When your web server receives a request with an 'If-Modified-Since' Monday, you send the new pass (because you know it changed on Thursday).

Comment: by your example , how I put the condition ? ( if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'])== ...? ){ ..... } )

Comment: how to put condition that it is difference from today ?

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work now for getting a pass. This is from console: Apr  9 09:35:32 CamMobs-iPod4 passd[2880] <Warning>: Get pass task (pass type pass.cam-mob.passbookpasstest, serial number 0001, if-modified-since (null); with web service url http://192.168.1.202:8888/passesWebserver/) got response with code 404

Comment: 404 is not found - this implies that your re-write rule is broken.

Comment: If I don't have any pass in my server, what should I change in header ? before I use ' header('Last-Modified: ' . date("D, d M Y H:i:s", filemtime('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/passesWebserver/DigiClubCard.pkpass')) . ' GMT+07:00');
'

Comment: I have answered your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16182486/how-to-get-last-modified-of-the-pass-that-is-added-by-user-dynamically) on how to set the `Last-Modified` header.