# How to respond for getting pass task

Tags: web-services, ios6, passbook

I am doing a web server for updating a pass. I test for updating by turn the toggle on or off for automatic updates. This is what I get from console: 
`Apr  8 13:19:47 CamMobs-iPod4 passd[21] <Warning>: Get pass task (pass type pass.cam-mob.passbookpasstest, serial number 0001, if-modified-since (null); with web service url http://192.168.1.202:8888/passesWebserver/) encountered error: Server response was malformed (Missing response data)`
This is the code I use:

```
if (strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) === "GET" && $request[3]==='passes'){

$passTypeID = $request[4];

$serial = $request[5];

 $auth_key = str_replace('ApplePass ', '', $headers['Authorization']);

$querySelect = mysql_query("select * from registration");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($querySelect);
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'])){
    if ($passTypeID == $row['passTypeID'] && $serial ==$row['serialNo']){
        $pkpass_file = '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/passesWebserver/DigiClubCard.pkpass';

        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Content-type: application/vnd.apple.pkpass; charset=UTF-8");
        header('Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="genericPass.pkpass"');
        clearstatcache();
        $filesize = filesize($pkpass_file);
        if ($filesize)
            header("Content-Length: ". $filesize);
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        if (filemtime($pkpass_file)) {
            date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
            header('Last-Modified: ' . date("D, d M Y H:i:s", filemtime($pkpass_file)) . ' GMT');
        }
        flush();
        readfile($pkpass_file);
    } } }`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting everything (*) from your registration table into `$row`, but then processing `$row` as if it is a MySQL row when it is actually a MySQL result.

Therefore your if statement is not triggering and so your code is sending back no content instead of the .pkpass bundle that passbook is expecting.

Comment: now when a pass is already updated, my server can respond 304, but why there's still some error ? this is from console I get: Apr  9 14:28:21 CamMobs-iPod4 passd[3521] <Warning>: Get pass task (pass type pass.cam-mob.passbookpasstest, serial number 0001, if-modified-since Tue, 09 Apr 2013 02:04:07 GMT; with web service url http://192.168.1.202:8888/passesWebserver/) got response with code 304

Comment: Apr  9 14:28:21 CamMobs-iPod4 passd[3521] <Warning>: Web service error for pass.cam-mob.passbookpasstest (http://192.168.1.202:8888/passesWebserver/): Server requested update to serial number '0001', but the pass was unchanged.

Comment: This is because you responded with an array of serial numbers but then when the device requested the pass with that serial, you send a `304`.  If the pass has not changed then you need to send a `204` to the get serials method AND a `304` to the Get latest version of a pass method.  If there is nothing in your phd_error.log, then check your log rewrite rule and check that your logging code if working properly.

Comment: my condition for getting serial number for pass is : $updateTag = array($row['max(updateTag)']);
 $tag = '';
 if(!empty($request[7]) && $request[7] === "passesUpdatedSince"){
      $tag = $request[8];
      error_log('Tag: ' .$tag,0);
    }
    if ($updateTag > $tag ) {
      echo json_encode(array('lastUpdated' => (string)time(), 
                           'serialNumbers' => $serialsArray)); 
  
    }else {
     response204();
 }

Comment: before 204 is called, but I cannot get pass, now I can get pass for first updating. For next updating, I get  response 200 for getting serial and 304 for getting pass

Comment: Your code is horrible!!  Assuming $row is now a MySQL row and not a result AND that you have changed your SQL query to include `MAX(updateTag) as updateTag` and `updateTag` is stored in your database as a MYSQL date, then your first statement should be `$updateTag = strtotime($row['updateTag']);` Then `passesUpdatedSince` is sent to the web service as a GET parameter, not as part of the URL so the condition to check is `if(!empty($_GET['passesUpadatedSince']))` and `$tag = $_GET['passesUpadatedSince']` not `$request[8]`.

Comment: After I change like you wrote above, I get this: [09-Apr-2013 11:23:02 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: updateTag in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/passesWebserver/index.php on line 97
and I cannot get pass for updating like before !

Comment: What is your query?  Sounds like you are not added `AS updateTag` to it.

Comment: I cannot get any serial and always get response 204!

Comment: $querySelect = mysql_query("SELECT serialNo, passTypeID, authenticationToken, MAX(updateTag) AS updateTag from digiCardPass"); 
 $updateTag = strtotime($row['updateTag']);
 $serialsArray = array($row['serialNo']); 
 
 if(!empty($_GET['passesUpadatedSince'])){
  $tag = $_GET['passesUpadatedSince'];
  error_log('Tag: ' .$tag,0);
    }
    if ($updateTag > $tag) {
      echo json_encode(array('lastUpdated' => (string)time(), 
                           'serialNumbers' => $serialsArray)); 
  
    }else {
     response204();
 }

Comment: That is correct because your pass has not changed - `204` means that your web service is correctly telling the device that it has nothing new to send it.  You can test this by changing the updateTag in the database to a date in the future and you should see a 200 response with serials.  Then you know for sure that it is working properly

Comment: no, I delete this pass and add again by app, but I cannot update it !

Comment: Do you still have the error in your log?  Where are you setting `$row`? What do you see in your log if you add `error_log(print_r($row, true),0);`

Comment: For getting the latest version pass, I use this this condition:  if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'])){
     header('HTTP/1.0 304 Not Modified');
     exit;
 }else{
 //get pass data

Comment: That is not great, because `$_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'])` will always be set meaning you will always be sending back a `304` header.  You need to check if the time of `$_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']` is less than the last modified time of the .pkpass file.

Comment: yes, it shows errors: [09-Apr-2013 11:42:54 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: row in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/passesWebserver/index.php on line 100
//101: '$updateTag = strtotime($row['updateTag']); ' '$serialsArray = array($row['serialNo']); '

Comment: Then it appears that you are not setting `$row`!  Try adding `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($querySelect);` after you have run your query

Comment: Do I need to select latest pass for getting serial and pass ?

Comment: I use the query above in two methods: for getting serial and getting latest version pass before giving a pass !

Comment: can I use same serial for the old and the updated pass ? or different serial ?

Comment: for my database now, I take serial, passTypeId and updateTag as primary key, so I can have same serial !

Comment: now I can update, but I still get this response: Apr  9 17:07:17 CamMobs-iPod4 passd[3813] <Warning>: Get serial #s task (for device 3681f4e7aab09b8c46af568fe8d6abfa, pass type pass.cam-mob.passbookpasstest, last updated 1365501517; with web service url http://192.168.1.202:8888/passesWebserver/) got response with code 200

Comment: Apr  9 17:07:18 CamMobs-iPod4 passd[3813] <Warning>: Get pass task (pass type pass.cam-mob.passbookpasstest, serial number 0001, if-modified-since Tue, 09 Apr 2013 02:04:07 GMT; with web service url http://192.168.1.202:8888/passesWebserver/) got response with code 304

Comment: for php_error.log, I get 1 error: [09-Apr-2013 12:07:17 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: tag in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/passesWebserver/index.php on line 108
//108     if ($updateTag > $tag) {
.........

Comment: Only you can really answer this question because only you know the structure of your database and how and when records will be added and updated.  For the getting the latest serials request, you need to return a list of any serials that have changed since the last update tag.  A better query for serials updated would be to to query where updateTag > $tag but for this to work properly you need to reconcile the date formats (or change updateTag from a date field to int and store a timestamp).  For getting latest pass, updateTag > strtotime($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']) may be better.

Comment: This means `$tag` is not set - you just had the same error with $row, surely you can figure this out for yourself!

Comment: How to see value of if-modified-since ? I use this: $ifms= strtotime($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']);  error_log('if-modified-since: '.$ifms,0);

Comment: This may be because there is no header being sent.  Look in XCode to see if the device is creating an `If-Modified-Since` header.

Comment: I can see if-modified-since: Apr 24 17:43:33 CamMobs-iPod4 passd[5333] <Warning>: Request contains header field <If-Modified-Since: Wed, 24 Apr 2013 10:35:31 GMT+07:00>

Comment: Then maybe your code is in the wrong part of your file - for example, it may be in an if statement that is not triggering.

Comment: in php_error.log, it shows: [24-Apr-2013 12:46:10 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/passesWebserver/getPassUpdated.php on line 21
//line 21:   $if= strtotime($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']);

Comment: I use this to check for getting pass: if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']) && strtotime($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']) > $lastUpdated) { 
     header('HTTP/1.0 304 Not Modified');
     exit;
 }

Comment: The error log is indicating that `$_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']` is undefined, so it is not seeing it.  You may be looking at a log entry from a different call since the device hits your web service with many different requests but not all of them have the `IF-MODIFIED-SINCE` header.  For your conditional check, it depends what is in $lastUpdated on whether or not there is an `IF-MODIFIED-SINCE` header.

Comment: in console , I always see if-modified-since , but how to get it to compare to updateTag ?

Comment: PHP is a single thread language - each call to your web service is independent and it has no memory between the calls it has previously received or serviced.  The lastUpdated tag is set in the serials call and the If-Modified-Since header is sent with the Get Latest Pass call. The only way you can compare something against the If-Modified-Since header is if you provide it to PHP while it is processing the call.  Personally, I store the lastUpdated tag in the DB and access it by selecting the pass record that matches the authToken, serial and passID the the Get Latest Pass method provides me.

Comment: I don't know why I get  this error again: [06-May-2013 06:55:46 Europe/Berlin] Passbook Error Log: [2013-05-06 11:55:45 +0700] Get pass task (pass type pass.cam-mob.passbookpasstest, serial number 3, if-modified-since (null); with web service url http://192.168.1.202/passesWebserver/webService/) encountered error: Server response was malformed (Missing response data)

Comment: getting latest version of pass method for iPhone works, but for iPod, it shows the error above!

Comment: This means that you are not sending a .pkpass bundle back with your response to the `Get Latest Version of a Pass` request.  If push is broken as well then roll back through the recent changes you made to your code.  Sounds like a change you have made elsewhere in your code may have caused this to break.

Comment: because get serial method only return 1 serial, but even I update for latest pass , it not work for iPod !

Comment: What have you changed since it was last working for iPod?  Things don't normally 'stop' working, they usually break as a consequence of changes you have made.

Comment: I am checking , before i can send both serials , now only 1 !

Comment: is push related to getting serial  ? when push send to both pushToken, no notification shows, but when push send to 1 pushToken, get serial is only 1 and it works !

Comment: The device only requests the serial after it has received the push.  You should be able to see the push arriving in Xcode.  If you are sending two pushes, then the two devices will issue two independent calls to the get serials method and you must recognise which device has called your service and respond with the correct data.

Comment: so if i send push to 2 devices , i will get 2 serials for getting serial method ? or 1 push , 1 serial ?

Comment: EACH DEVICE that receives a push will send 1 request for serials and it needs to receive a response with ONE serial that is EQUAL TO the serial of the pass installed on THAT DEVICE.  Number of successful pushes == Number of Requests your web service will receive.

Comment: why iPod get this for getting pass : [06-May-2013 08:51:09 Europe/Berlin] Passbook Error Log: [2013-05-06 13:51:08 +0700] Get pass task (pass type pass.cam-mob.passbookpasstest, serial number 6, if-modified-since (null); with web service url http://192.168.1.202/passesWebserver/webService/) encountered error: Server response was malformed (Missing response data)

Comment: and iPhone get this : May  6 13:51:37 ML-iphone-5 passd[2121] <Warning>: Get pass task (pass type pass.cam-mob.passbookpasstest, serial number 1, if-modified-since Mon, 06 May 2013 13:41:30 GMT + 7; with web service url http://192.168.1.202/passesWebserver/webService/) got response with code 200

Comment: Check your `Get Latest Version of a Pass Method`.  You are either not responding properly, or the .pkpass you are sending back for serial 6 is corrupt.

Comment: Do I have to loop in getting latest version of pass method for many serials ?

Comment: You will never have to loop - `Get Latest Version of a Pass Method` can only ever send one response to one device.  Remember that PHP runs on a single thread.  There is no way that it can service two devices in the same runtime. Both requests to you PHP script are independent and should ONLY return the serial given by the request.

Comment: now I get this error : May  7 10:37:51 CamMobs-iPod4 passd[21097] <Warning>: Too many pushes too fast for pass.cam-mob.passbookpasstest -- severe rate limiting will apply.

Comment: and getting serial method is not called !

Comment: Marker - May 7, 2013 10:41:57 AM
[07-May-2013 05:42:13 Europe/Berlin] 07-05-2013 0505:4242:1313: APNS Message successfully sent to push token 43401d1da3132a04f444bb70ccb0c22636a57119aa004dc815a95b61d462c2bb
[07-May-2013 05:42:14 Europe/Berlin] 07-05-2013 0505:4242:1414: APNS Message successfully sent to push token 8fdd14fd1b8f317ddd501ce50aefe631e8ceda46bce865ae30e2d1c37ccc060e
[07-May-2013 05:42:14 Europe/Berlin] Stream Response: 47

Comment: Looks like you have pissed Apple off ;-)  Best to wait a while before testing again.

Comment: Yes - these are their production servers.  You cannot use the Sandbox for Passbook.  Their official guidance is not to rapidly open and close sockets, you should just keep a single socket open and push new messages through that.  Unfortunately, you don't have the infrastructure or skills to do this.  Opening and closing a socket for low volume, occasional pushes is OK, but if you have been doing this multiple times a minute, then you are putting an unnecessary burden on Apple's production server which is why they are now throttling you.

Comment: so what should I do ? I don't to close connection as I have many pushnotifications !

Comment: now I comment the code that close connection and sockets, but I still get that error !

Comment: May  7 10:59:26 CamMobs-iPod4 passd[21186] <Warning>: Too many pushes too fast for pass.cam-mob.passbookpasstest -- severe rate limiting will apply.

Comment: You will still get the error and you will still have these problems because PHP only has one thread and once it finishes executing, it dies and frees up all resources (and will automatically close the connection even though you are not closing it) - it has no memory of what happened between requests.  If you want to keep a socket open, with PHP then you need to run PHP as a daemon.  Then need to write code to poll some sort of queue holding your updates - but this is very advanced, given your current level of knowledge and experience.

Comment: You still can push one at a time, but you need to a) wait a while and b) fix up your code so that when you do receive a push, everything works as it should.  Do you have someone more experienced at CamMob that could take a look at your code and help explain things to you?

Comment: They are busy with their project ! if I post my code of pushnotification on another question, will someone look and explain it ?