# How to get last-modified of the pass that is added by user dynamically

Tags: ios6, header, last-modified, passbook

Before I had a pass in my server and I got last-modified by using this:
`header('Last-Modified: ' . date("D, d M Y H:i:s", filemtime('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/passesWebserver/DigiClubCard.pkpass')) . ' GMT+07:00');`
 
Now I don't have any pass in my server and I only have data of pass in database, so what should I change this header in order to get last-modified of the pass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sending a new, dynamically created pass, to create a header with the current time you can:

```
// Tell PHP to use UTC
date_default_timezone_set ('UTC');

// Create a header with the current time
header('Last-Modified: ' . date("D, d M Y H:i:s", time()) . ' GMT');
```

With regards to the *timezone*, Section 3.3.1 of the HTTP/1.1 standard [**RFC2616**](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.3) states:

> All HTTP date/time stamps MUST be represented in Greenwich Mean Time
>   (GMT),  without exception. For the purposes of HTTP, GMT is exactly
>   equal to UTC  (Coordinated Universal Time). This is indicated in the
>   first two formats by  the inclusion of "GMT" as the three-letter
>   abbreviation for time zone, and  MUST be assumed when reading the
>   asctime format. HTTP-date is case sensitive  and MUST NOT include
>   additional LWS beyond that specifically included as SP in  the
>   grammar.

so you should not be adding on 7 hours to GMT.

Comment: so I need to add this when I create a pass or when getting serial of pass for webservice ?

Comment: How to know last-modified of the pass in user's device  ?

Comment: You only need to send this header with a .pkpass.  You should send it with the first pass, and in response to the `Get Latest Version of a Pass` method.  Devices will echo your `Last-Modified` date in the `If-Modified-Since` header they send with the `Get Latest Version of a Pass` request.

Comment: so for getting the Serial Numbers for Passes Associated with a Device, I don't need to add header like before !

Comment: No - adding it before was never necessary. For the serials method you add a `lastUpdated` key to your JSON response.

Comment: before, I use this: echo json_encode(array('lastUpdated' => (string)time(), 
                           'serialNumbers' => $serialsArray));

Comment: I don't need to change this ?

Comment: No need to change - your current code is fine, just no need to send a `Last-Modified` header with the serials response.

Comment: what about getting the Latest Version of a Pass ? what should I respond for getting pass task ? before, I read pkpass, but now ..... ?

Comment: This is where you would dynamically create the new pass, which would create a .pkpass bundle on disk somewhere (usually in a temp folder), then you would read that file.

Comment: so I need to create a new pass dynamically if I see that there's new pass  in pass table ?

Comment: Logic should be - receive 'Get latest pass' request with `If-Modified-Since` header -> check database to see if pass with that serial and passTypeID has changed since the `If-Modified-Since` date -> if no, send `304` response -> if yes, dynamically generate new pass and send with new `Last-Modified` header.